# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel , RestRequest

Tags: c#, ssl, request

I have read most of the answers about this error in the stackoverflow . But this error still persists.

this is a part of my code

```
                RestClient client = new RestClient($"{baseUrl}/user/store")
                {
                    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(apiUser, apiPassword)
                };
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

                RestRequest request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);
                request.AddQueryParameter("countryCode", countryCode);
                request.AddQueryParameter("mobile", mobileNumber);
                request.AddQueryParameter("device_id", macAddress);
                request.AddQueryParameter("device_os", deviceOs);
                request.AddQueryParameter("version", version);
                
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

in this line
`IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);` error has occurred

I use `.netfrearmwork 4.7.2` and `wpf` in `Windows 7`

How can i fix this ?
Can this error be related to the server ?

Comment: Do you have TLS 1.2 enabled? Not necessarily true on Windows 7 considering how old it is and out of support

Comment: yes @Charlieface . I enabled TLS 1.2 According to this video 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LK7-YNpxEhA